# Internet Problem on Ubuntu VM using WIFI

Tags: virtualbox, internet

I installed Ubuntu virtual machines on Ubuntu 18.04 OS. Initially the internet was running. But now I can't access the internet.
My ifconfig command is not working. I have attached the information about the NETWORK of the machine.

Somebody please guide. Yesterday I installed Kali but I got the same internet problem. I thought I won't get this problem on Ubuntu but I am getting this problem on Ubuntu also. I have installed the Ubuntu from OSboxes. File name is U19_10_VB-64bit.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.[image: Network Adapter1[![][1]]][ifconfig command]
[[image: Network Information]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4TP.jpg)

Comment: In your VM, does `ping 8.8.8.8` work and get replies?  If it is getting ping replies, then the issue is DNS within your VM, and we can fix that.  If not, then the VM networking is either not configured or not connected properly.  And we can work to debug that as well.

Comment: Hi, I am getting destination host unreachable. ping 8.8.8.8 not working. I have got 3 clones. And internet is not working on all of them. Initially it was working. I got some message related to some problem occurred and since I am getting this problem. It showed me a window asking me to send the problem or not. I send  the problem.

Comment: I found that the internet stops working if I use NATNetwork option. If I use NAT option internet will keep running but is it possible to have different IP addresses in case of NAT option

Comment: I have to use Bridged Adapter. All my machines are connected to internet now.